# Google Analytics Filter - Filtering out URL Parameters

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have the following urls:

**example.org/**

**example.org/index.cfm**

**example.org/index.cfm?SSO=1**

...all of which point the the same page. In GA, I want them all to point to 
 **example.org/**. Every month, I have to add up the data for each of these, and it's quite annoying.

I'm aware of how filters work, and I have the following:

Search & Replace > Request URI

**Search String:** index.cfm$

**Replace String:** (left the field blank)

...and that's working.

The issue is when I'm trying to search & replace or exclude the "?SSO=1" from the string. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Rather than using filters you should go to the view settings and use the 
"Exclude URL Query Parameters" field (enter a comma separated list of the parameters you want to be removed).

Comment: Depending on where the params sit, sometimes I need everything after the & to be removed, and sometimes it's after the ?. Because of my unique URL structure, we had to put "&itemnumber" into an advanced search and replace filter. The "exclude url query params" option wouldn't have helped us in this case... Thanks!